# MySQL UPDATE not working when first subquery = 0

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following query to update my payment table in order to set it equal to the sum of all charges minus the sum of all payments and credits in a customer database.

This works perfectly as long as there is a charge, however, if the first subquery is equal to zero it does not update payment.balance to a negative number, it simply remains zero.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this or why this is?

```
UPDATE customer 
   SET balance = (SELECT SUM(amount) 
                    FROM payment 
                   WHERE type = 'C'
                     AND custID = '10003') 
               - (SELECT SUM(amount) 
                    FROM payment 
                   WHERE (type = 'P' OR type = 'X') 
                     AND custID = '10003') 
 WHERE custID = '10003';
```

So in brief summary, when the first subquery `(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment WHERE type = 'C' AND custID = '10003')` is `0`, the update always results in `0` instead of `0` minus the second subquery.

Thoughts?

Comment: what is the data type of the column `balance`

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Double(8,2) NOT NULL Default 0.00

Comment: and did you check the output of both the sub-queries individually?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky I just did because of Elijah's answer below and found it was null. I used IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) to fix the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being that I cannot see your actual db table column setup I'm guessing this.

MySQL SUM() function returns the sum of an expression. SUM() function returns NULL when the return set has no rows.

Use an if condition so in the event that SUM() yields NULL then have the value returned as 0 so you never have NULL - x or x - NULL or NULL - NULL.

Comment: That sounds about right; I will try it and get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer that did the trick! I used IFNULL(SUM(amount),0).

Comment: may i also suggest to update the schema for those columns so the default value will be 0 instead of null. Otherwise every time you try something against the data you will have to always remember to put in an if checker.